# SQLException: Access denied for user 'whatever'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Credentials are correct, database name is correct, MySQL users are set correctly and have all the privileges, I have entries for 'username'@'%' as well as 'username'@'localhost', I can connect to this user via commandline correctly, as well as through mysql workbench. In other words, everything works as it should and is set as it should be, except my java app is unable to connect.

I did about 3 clean uninstalls and installs of MySQL, with restarts, without restarts, tried to login through app as root (with pass) which didn't work, tried to login through app as user with no password (same error), etc.

Also, a PHP website running on localhost using precisely the same login works perfectly.

I've been checking and re-checking and trying all of this for the past 3 days, I went through all the related SO questions, all the blogs and docs I could find, all of it.

```
try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/correctDBname", "correctUsername", "correctPassword");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(SqlConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

MySQL driver name precisely as it appears in NetBeans' "Libraries" section in project: **MySQL JDBC Driver - mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar**

Full text of the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'strada'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at eu.storemedia.stradaserver.engine.SqlConnection.<init>(SqlConnection.java:23)
at eu.storemedia.stradaserver.engine.StradaServer.<init>(StradaServer.java:51)
at eu.storemedia.stradaserver.Home.<clinit>(Home.java:31)
```

Comment: At least add the exception you get to your question

Comment: What version of the MySql driver are you using?

Comment: @Robin sorry, you're right adding it to OP

Comment: @RobertoLinares added to OP. MySQL JDBC Driver - mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar

Comment: You haven't put any port on your connection URL (Ej. 3306) after localhost. Is that correct?

Comment: @RobertoLinares including or omitting port number makes no difference, i've been trying that variant as well, with all the other setup combinations I've tried.

Comment: @RobertoLinares The driver defaults to port 3306 if none is specified.

Comment: Consider upgrading the driver, 5.1.23 is from 2013, latest version is 5.1.41, for example you might have a bug fixed in 5.1.27 (_"JDBC authentication failed when there was a null byte in the scramble, because com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake only read up to the first null byte when reading in the first eight bytes of the scramble. (Bug #16723048, Bug #62469)"_)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've upgraded to the latest, no change in the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...turns out reading credentials from .txt file might be dangerous, and omitting this fact from the question in the name of simplifying it was a mistake.

**if I use hardcoded credentials, login works. If I use credentials read from incorrectly created .txt file, the error occurs. If I use credentials read from correctly created .txt file (utf-8 with no BOM), login works.**

I've rewritten the file I'm reading the credentials from to be correct, so I can't find out any specifics, but basically **it contained some invisible character (possibly BOM) that was making the credentials invalid.**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you carefully go through each and every one of the suggestions in the MySQL Manual's section on connection troubleshooting.

- ["Troubleshooting Problems Connecting to MySQL"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-connecting.html)

Also, check the Connector/J troubleshooting page:

- ["Troubleshooting Connector/J Applications"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html)

The latter page includes this useful tip:

> Note: Testing your connectivity with the mysql command-line client will not work unless you add the "host" flag, and use something other than localhost for the host. The mysql command-line client will use Unix domain sockets if you use the special host name localhost. **If you are testing connectivity to localhost, use 127.0.0.1 as the host name instead.**

This says ... in effect ... that you *may not be* checking the actual connection method that the JDBC driver is using.  It could make a difference to authentication.

Comment: thanks for this. tried
mysql --host=127.0.01 --port=3306 -u correctUsername -p
and
mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 -u correctUsername -p

on commandline and both connected successfully, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have different versions of mysql installed at the same time and you have registered in the enviroment variables another mysql version. Try to check if you have something that you can uninstall. Then, add to the enviroment variable the right mysql in the right folder.

Comment: No, only single version but environment variable was pointing to an incorrect folder. Fixed, will restart and try again after replying to the rest of comments here

Comment: Great! Please report us what you got after trying

Answer (score 0):

**Access denied for user 'strada'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

The Exception explains the following:

1. 'strada' user do not have enough privileges for performing the operation in DB.
2. 'using password: YES' means- The password provided for user 'strada' is  right.

**Fix:**

1. Login as root user to DB, provide user 'strada' with DBA (Database Administrator) previlage.
2. Reconnect using Correct JDBC connection string.

Comment: if you read the original question properly, you'd know that your "answer" deserves a downvote which I, unluckily, don't have enough reputation to give you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/correctDBname", "correctUsername", "correctPassword");
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: including or omitting port number makes no difference.