# MySql Connection Refused - Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So today I decided my website would run faster if I moved our databases to a different server, so I did, you can see how I am connecting below:

```java
final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            final String url = "jdbc:mysql://external_ip_address_here:3306/dbname";
            final String username = "user";
            final String password = "pass";
            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

This works fine when I am connecting to `127.0.0.1` / `localhost`, now I am getting this error:

> java.net.ConnectException
>   MESSAGE: Connection refused (Connection refused)

My MySQL server is running Ubuntu 18.04.

I added multiple firewall rules to try and allow all incoming connections to port 3306 - `sudo ufw allow from any to any port 3306 proto tcp` & I tried `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`, still not working, when i port scan the network it shows port 3306 as closed

FIX 1: This fixed the connection refused error -
Step 1: edit file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
Step 2: remove line `bind-address           = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Is the external_ip_address_here reachable ? Try pinging if it is enabled.

Comment: Most likely you didn't configure everything on DB server properly, check this question it might help your: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318250/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-mysql-database-with-java

Comment: @Amanjangra it is reachable

Comment: @Amanjangra its saying 3306 port is closed

Comment: @MakeN did you tried connecting it though any sql developer IDE's from the box where you are running your application.

Comment: ya, managed to actually start connecting to it, now I am getting another error ;( -> `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'hostname' (using password: YES)`, 99.99% sure I am using correct password.

Answer (score 1):

Check the servers firewall configurations. It may be the reason for your problem. Add a new rule that allows connection from your URL in firewall settings.

Comment: I added multiple firewall rules to try and allow all incoming connections to port 3306 - `sudo ufw allow from any to any port 3306 proto tcp` & I tried `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`, still not working, when i port scan the network it shows port 3306 as closed

Comment: Try restarting the iptables service afterwards, which OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04, this error is fixed now as you can see in the edited message, I am having a new problem -  `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'hostname' (using password: YES)`, I am using correct details.

Comment: See this, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43088226/5804036

Comment: Sadly it did not, I will probably create a new question for this to get more answers, is there a way for me to close this?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96283

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the connection refused error -

Step 1: edit file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Step 2: remove line `bind-address           = 127.0.0.1`